# C# Setup Wizard don't install all of my project needed file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developping a console c# app .NET core 3.0 . I've created a Setup Wizard who contains only principal output.

The problem is when i'm installing my program, the setup install only 2 files.

```
-ProjectName.dll
-ProjectName.runtimeconfig.json
```

I can't find the .exe after installation

I need install .NET framework during installation of my program so I configure the installation URL (path on my network) to the .exe of installation but that's not work.

I've go a Build Output without errors nor warnings :

```
- ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'ProjectName' ------ 
- ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'ProjectName' ------ 
- ------ Pre-build validation for project 'ProjectName' completed ------
- ------ Pre-build validation for project 'ProjectName' completed ------
- 1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : ProjectName, Configuration : Release ------
- 1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : ProjectName, Configuration : Release ------
- Building file 'C:\Users\blabla\source\repos\Setup_ProjectName\Release\Setup_ProjectName.msi'...
- Building file 'C:\Users\blabla\source\repos\Setup_ProjectName\Release\Setup_ProjectName.msi'...
- Packaging file 'ProjectName.dll'...
- Packaging file 'ProjectName.dll'...
- Packaging file 'ProjectName.runtimeconfig.json'...
- Packaging file 'ProjectName.runtimeconfig.json'...
- ========== Génération : 1 a réussi, 0 a échoué, 1 mis à jour, 0 a été ignoré ==========
```

Thx for help.

Comment: So.. advise the end-user on installing the .net redistributor, or provide as necessary given licensing constraints?  Can you [edit] your question to clarify?  It sounds like you just need to provide instructions, or the necessary prerequisites.  Otherwise, I'm not sure of what the issue is.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a point for you, but you can take a look at self-contained apps (https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/). So, you can publish a single *.exe file, which will include dotnet runtime.

Comment: The EXE is dotnet.exe.  Not unlike mono.exe, python.exe, java.exe.  You can build a self-contained version, but that is going to significantly blow up the installer.  Not much core left in .netcore.  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: I'm not even sure you're looking for .net runtime installations.  *Are you trying to find the compiled version of your program, and cannot?*  Did you check in `/bin/release` in the project folder?